# Firefox: lose focus when clear textbox value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, firefox, textbox

I have a search box (textbox) and I want to clear it's content when I click inside. (some kind of watermark. Watermark control was not good for me in this case).
I am using "onKeyDown" event to clear the content:

```
 function clearTbSearch(tbSearch) {

        if (tbSearch != null && tbSearch.value == '<%= TypeHereText %>') {

            tbSearch.value = "";


            tbSearch.style.color = "#000000";

        }
        return true;
    }
```

It works fine in IE and Chrome but in Firefox it takes 3 (!!!) clicks to get it focused. First click does not do anything. The second one clears the textbox but do not focus. The third click get the cursor focused. I tried anything... I would be glad for any suggestions...
Thanks!!!

Comment: with HTML5, you can simply say `<input type="text" placeholder="Some placeholder text">` for rendering a watermarked textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to make it look cleaner:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" value="Your initial trademark" onfocus="this.value=''" />
```

Comment: Thanks,It is working, but it also called on first load of the page, deleting the watermark...

Comment: I think your initial content won't be cleared unless the user click on the field. It should be similar to this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/E3v2B/) rite?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `onkeydown` event, just use the generic `onfocus` instead:

```
var firstTime = true;
window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("MyInput");
    input.onfocus = function() {
        if (!firstTime)
            clearTbSearch(this);
        firstTime = false;
    };
    input.focus();
};
```

This way it will work either by keyboard focus or mouse focus e.g. when clicking the textbox.

Comment: Thanks,It is working, but it also called on first load of the page, deleting the watermark...